# What does this crash report tell me about why my app fails to start?

Tags: ios, crash, exc-bad-access

Apple told me that that my app crashes on startup. This is the crash report, but I don't know what it means. What is the probable cause?

```
CrashReporter Key:   8ebc5eb666109db6d4970a4148cf88160f6805b5
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             Music Player [907]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/664B5DFA-4F34-4469-B30D-EC43B25F39E0/Music Player.app/Music Player
Version:             1.0 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-01-17 10:11:49.478 -0800
Launch Time:         2015-01-17 10:11:28.916 -0800
OS Version:          iOS 8.1 (12B410)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
com.ceto.ocakonbes failed to scene-create in time

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 0.270 (user 0.270, system 0.000), 8% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.007, 0% CPU

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196928eb8 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019680ea4c _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 252
2   CFNetwork                       0x0000000184f354e0 CFURLConnectionSendSynchronousRequest + 284
3   CFNetwork                       0x0000000184f55bc8 +[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:] + 116
4   Music Player                    0x00000001000c20a0 0x100094000 + 188576
5   Music Player                    0x00000001000b15b8 0x100094000 + 120248
6   UIKit                           0x0000000189d1ce80 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 688
7   UIKit                           0x0000000189dd2374 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 60
8   UIKit                           0x0000000189dd2270 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 244
9   UIKit                           0x0000000189dd170c -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 108
10  UIKit                           0x0000000189dd13b8 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 636
11  UIKit                           0x0000000189dd10d8 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 52
12  UIKit                           0x0000000189dd1058 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 196
13  UIKit                           0x0000000189d19a28 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 568
14  QuartzCore                      0x0000000189671990 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 164
15  QuartzCore                      0x000000018966c560 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 316
16  QuartzCore                      0x000000018966c404 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 28
17  QuartzCore                      0x000000018966bc04 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 272
18  QuartzCore                      0x000000018966b988 CA::Transaction::commit() + 432
19  UIKit                           0x0000000189fa7014 -[UIApplication _reportMainSceneUpdateFinished:] + 56
20  UIKit                           0x0000000189fa7ec0 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 2776
21  UIKit                           0x0000000189fa6044 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 180
22  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018d7b563c __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 24
23  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185526120 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16
24  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185525228 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 308
25  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018552384c __CFRunLoopRun + 1752
26  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001854511f0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
27  UIKit                           0x0000000189d87788 -[UIApplication _run] + 548
28  UIKit                           0x0000000189d82780 UIApplicationMain + 1484
29  Music Player                    0x000000010009a270 0x100094000 + 25200
30  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019682aa04 start + 0

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196928c94 kevent64 + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019681097c _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 272
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001968033b0 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 48

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196943c78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001969dd390 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001969dcfa4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3 name:  WebThread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001969430c0 __psynch_mutexwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001969dd548 _pthread_mutex_lock + 416
2   WebCore                         0x00000001932b1dc8 _WebTryThreadLock(bool) + 120
3   WebCore                         0x00000001932b1d2c WebRunLoopLock(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 40
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185526148 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001855230d4 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 356
6   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001855235a8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1076
7   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001854511f0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
8   WebCore                         0x00000001932affe8 RunWebThread(void*) + 464
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001969dfe7c _pthread_body + 160
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001969dfdd8 _pthread_start + 156
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001969dcfac thread_start + 0

Thread 4 name:  AdColony Worker
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196928e7c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196928cf4 mach_msg + 68
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001855255c8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018552351c __CFRunLoopRun + 936
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001854511f0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
5   Foundation                      0x0000000186355800 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 312
6   Music Player                    0x000000010011d1e0 0x100094000 + 561632
7   Foundation                      0x000000018643dc08 __NSThread__main__ + 1068
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001969dfe7c _pthread_body + 160
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001969dfdd8 _pthread_start + 156
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001969dcfac thread_start + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196943c78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001969dd390 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001969dcfa4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196928e7c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196928cf4 mach_msg + 68
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001855255c8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018552351c __CFRunLoopRun + 936
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001854511f0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
5   CFNetwork                       0x0000000184f556a0 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 436
6   Foundation                      0x000000018643dc08 __NSThread__main__ + 1068
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001969dfe7c _pthread_body + 160
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001969dfdd8 _pthread_start + 156
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001969dcfac thread_start + 0

Thread 7 name:  JavaScriptCore::BlockFree
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196943078 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001969defe0 _pthread_cond_wait + 620
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x000000019593ccac std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 52
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001869d95f8 JSC::BlockAllocator::blockFreeingThreadMain() + 228
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001869d4b7c WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 20
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001969dfe7c _pthread_body + 160
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001969dfdd8 _pthread_start + 156
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001969dcfac thread_start + 0

Thread 8 name:  JavaScriptCore::Marking
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196943078 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001969defe0 _pthread_cond_wait + 620
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x000000019593ccac std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 52
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186c828b8 JSC::GCThread::waitForNextPhase() + 152
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186c8295c JSC::GCThread::gcThreadMain() + 88
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001869d4b7c WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 20
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001969dfe7c _pthread_body + 160
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001969dfdd8 _pthread_start + 156
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001969dcfac thread_start + 0

Thread 9 name:  JavaScriptCore::Marking
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196943078 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001969defe0 _pthread_cond_wait + 620
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x000000019593ccac std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 52
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186c828b8 JSC::GCThread::waitForNextPhase() + 152
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186c8295c JSC::GCThread::gcThreadMain() + 88
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001869d4b7c WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 20
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001969dfe7c _pthread_body + 160
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001969dfdd8 _pthread_start + 156
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001969dcfac thread_start + 0

Thread 10 name:  com.apple.coremedia.player.async
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196928eb8 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019680ea4c _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 252
2   MediaToolbox                    0x00000001878fd0c8 fpa_AsyncMovieControlThread + 1952
3   CoreMedia                       0x0000000185d825d0 figThreadMain + 244
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001969dfe7c _pthread_body + 160
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001969dfdd8 _pthread_start + 156
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001969dcfac thread_start + 0

Thread 11 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196943498 __select + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018552afc0 __CFSocketManager + 656
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001969dfe7c _pthread_body + 160
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001969dfdd8 _pthread_start + 156
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001969dcfac thread_start + 0

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196943c78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001969dd390 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001969dcfa4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196943c78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001969dd390 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001969dcfa4 start_wqthread + 0

No thread state (register information) available
Binary Images:
0x100094000 - 0x10035ffff Music Player arm64  <57868f5b184f36a582ba801ef3783992> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/664B5DFA-4F34-4469-B30D-EC43B25F39E0/Music Player.app/Music Player
0x1200b4000 - 0x1200dbfff dyld arm64  <f958ba064181388a9658f927da42e9e7> /usr/lib/dyld
0x183d48000 - 0x183edbfff AVFoundation arm64  <0c542593e3613f82b7e860cb5beeeed6> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x1841bc000 - 0x184263fff libBLAS.dylib arm64  <e5276e7784ef34a4baca480264978ea0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x184264000 - 0x1845defff libLAPACK.dylib arm64  <165b05f9f75736d5ae8f5f39293bd6e7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x1845f8000 - 0x184660fff libvDSP.dylib arm64  <004f5668574139bc906c5fa4fdced3b1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x18468c000 - 0x1846bafff Accounts arm64  <ed248dc14d9c38feb7a61bdd532db9cc> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x1846bc000 - 0x1846bcfff AdSupport arm64  <977faefc983d3d72ad5e531740e4130a> /System/Library/Frameworks/AdSupport.framework/AdSupport
0x1846c0000 - 0x184742fff AddressBook arm64  <191fcc882bb8300b90b0b6b55cc7eec0> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x184744000 - 0x184894fff AddressBookUI arm64  <0d4f38d8108e3fc281fa3571f5f85bd4> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x184898000 - 0x1848abfff AssetsLibrary arm64  <a8106dcd3a703747b10b3dd9e609576e> /System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/AssetsLibrary
0x189664000 - 0x1897e8fff QuartzCore arm64  <376edab4d56635ec984b87b7a1702de0> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x18c58c000 - 0x18c6c3fff CoreMediaStream arm64  <c3e144da537d3c94bc12e58435b49c1d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreMediaStream.framework/CoreMediaStream
0x18c6c4000 - 0x18c774fff CorePDF arm64  <adf469f9c026312683165e9c4af258c4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CorePDF.framework/CorePDF
0x18c7e8000 - 0x18c7f3fff CoreRecents arm64  <8be1636faf27390bbf3a4a6517df51f9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreRecents.framework/CoreRecents
0x18c880000 - 0x18c8a4fff CoreServicesInternal arm64  <88aea9acfb373a28b285a7d252825b85> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreServicesInternal.framework/CoreServicesInternal
0x18cb08000 - 0x18cb9afff CoreUI arm64  <8e33909dd1f43590bae63cf4d4991e34> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/CoreUI
0x18cb9c000 - 0x18cc17fff CoreUtils arm64  <52b4bea57e9538a4ac29870663099d58> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUtils.framework/CoreUtils
0x18cc18000 - 0x18cc1efff CrashReporterSupport arm64  <a7fda94a40ea34149b6bce8d445dc863> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x18cc20000 - 0x18cc27fff DAAPKit arm64  <ed341cafa6743a6f9305f98a5b8f5781> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DAAPKit.framework/DAAPKit
0x18cc28000 - 0x18cc33fff DCIMServices arm64  <6620c9b0da2f3955bdb2b3ddf1d0596a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DCIMServices.framework/DCIMServices
0x18cc34000 - 0x18cc83fff DataAccess arm64  <1105560511863eb4b050878bd140bbb6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x18cee0000 - 0x18cf06fff DataAccessExpress arm64  <505a289392f53ec8876896504d322c81> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x18cf14000 - 0x18cf30fff DataDetectorsCore arm64  <822b0eee14c834dca63c74d02b02b593> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/DataDetectorsCore
0x18cf38000 - 0x18cf54fff DataDetectorsUI arm64  <0e08e67cdd8736379009e917e7b4cd36> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsUI.framework/DataDetectorsUI
0x18cf58000 - 0x18cf5ffff DataMigration arm64  <08afb9df68c13565bff259d40bcebda4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x18cf68000 - 0x18cf69fff DiagnosticLogCollection arm64  <7e3171d82a413732a9bc272d1557bdc1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DiagnosticLogCollection.framework/DiagnosticLogCollection
0x18cf6c000 - 0x18cf8cfff DictionaryServices arm64  <4f4e43c76ec834af8829e0bc89dbe53b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x18cfb4000 - 0x18cfdafff EAP8021X arm64  <7d312758fb02305dacd9c276be5f4ad4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x18f2b8000 - 0x18f2c1fff MobileInstallation arm64  <4237916a7e463bb5b534a1fe18ec9996> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x18f2c4000 - 0x18f2d3fff MobileKeyBag arm64  <873549823b5a329fac3e286fe251323a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x18f310000 - 0x18f313fff MobileSystemServices arm64  <dd7f149bbce035aab65259ea3ca82811> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSystemServices.framework/MobileSystemServices
0x18f33c000 - 0x18f34dfff MobileWiFi arm64  <d4c11a38e87438a7a4aac351b181e37d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x18f39c000 - 0x18f577fff MusicLibrary arm64  <ef23913206d13ad0a37757f0f3670e5b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
0x18f644000 - 0x18f64afff Netrb arm64  <32f0e0e39fbc3a99a9710a42e9672546> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Netrb.framework/Netrb
0x18f64c000 - 0x18f653fff NetworkStatistics arm64  <68b2e2e2eb6f31ef833df27acdc6a0af> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetworkStatistics.framework/NetworkStatistics
0x18f654000 - 0x18f676fff Notes arm64  <8818ebab9a613c4dbc6cc8e909f60d82> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x1907bc000 - 0x190803fff PrintKit arm64  <583123e28f123ae287cb5dfab1a44089> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x190808000 - 0x1908c7fff ProofReader arm64  <b48197ce226f33458b5796e6a5102634> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x1908c8000 - 0x1908dbfff ProtectedCloudStorage arm64  <12a0c66681c5399fb48410209d3c119c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtectedCloudStorage.framework/ProtectedCloudStorage
0x1908dc000 - 0x1908eafff ProtocolBuffer arm64  <e3c918ededc73b5c8e5d614ab7cc6369> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x190928000 - 0x1909a6fff Quagga arm64  <710b4d3d34a5315cb5219004ddafade8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Quagga.framework/Quagga
0x190c04000 - 0x190ca5fff SAObjects arm64  <5a99fbe9f7263103af786f24a859473d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SAObjects.framework/SAObjects
0x190e58000 - 0x190e77fff SpringBoardServices arm64  <7c1eba620c64347c84054f13dfbfc4e1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x19126c000 - 0x1913b3fff StoreServices arm64  <81f688f29d3931c2a4249062935d3ed8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x1914a4000 - 0x1914a7fff TCC arm64  <3cef7e15716d3f639b91a4f794311fea> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
0x1914f8000 - 0x19153bfff TelephonyUtilities arm64  <c072bc440d9335dca3d31ed7f6b58382> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUtilities.framework/TelephonyUtilities
0x192694000 - 0x1926c1fff TextInput arm64  <f6141f34ddbb3340ab7f58cba9d6b196> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x192794000 - 0x19286cfff UIFoundation arm64  <2a06496ae99434d498eaa5976988da0e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation
0x19289c000 - 0x19289ffff UserFS arm64  <6ad0dd6b74a631acbb33493e22c14ca7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UserFS.framework/UserFS
0x1930f0000 - 0x193114fff VoiceServices arm64  <54bcfc78fd2e37fa91ee5f50a7cff6f0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VoiceServices.framework/VoiceServices
0x1931b8000 - 0x1931e0fff WebBookmarks arm64  <1eb043cb594d3ee5bf04e9d5c2d7b138> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x193200000 - 0x194125fff WebCore arm64  <951d36df17bf3ecd8904ef3340b6c761> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x194128000 - 0x1941fafff WebKitLegacy arm64  <585af940902039a78ada10b6fd57d843> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKitLegacy.framework/WebKitLegacy
0x1943c8000 - 0x1943cffff XPCKit arm64  <ae7f648463e63cf8a2a9d52b7f7c2a9c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XPCKit.framework/XPCKit
0x1943d0000 - 0x1943d9fff XPCObjects arm64  <daf7c652a40738ee8ab9a7ee98492ef1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XPCObjects.framework/XPCObjects
0x194604000 - 0x19460afff iAdServices arm64  <c0a61fa3d05534fcb9997f591ef55a3a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iAdServices.framework/iAdServices
0x19460c000 - 0x194636fff iCalendar arm64  <747b0e23df5c3ef5912d0e415bbe9563> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x19486c000 - 0x1948aefff iTunesStore arm64  <e82efd67579732cba2c039d741dfffa3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iTunesStore.framework/iTunesStore
0x195204000 - 0x19520dfff libAccessibility.dylib arm64  <1608d9b29a343c2997a599274f53f67c> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x1954a0000 - 0x1954bbfff libCRFSuite.dylib arm64  <4809980f357b33d08735e2d5c2f27cc6> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x1954fc000 - 0x195633fff libFosl_dynamic.dylib arm64  <3013ac9596c03e458767997983ac758f> /usr/lib/libFosl_dynamic.dylib
0x195654000 - 0x195655fff libMobileCheckpoint.dylib arm64  <475fb3275f6831c98e7cff68340295a3> /usr/lib/libMobileCheckpoint.dylib
0x195658000 - 0x195672fff libMobileGestalt.dylib arm64  <b6b70a42eba93a8aafe97b9560970330> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x1956a4000 - 0x1956a5fff libSystem.B.dylib arm64  <85311cdfce9a37178346f06cfea6dc94> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x195728000 - 0x195776fff libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib arm64  <801a901787c730cbbf3167be0de5ea42> /usr/lib/libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib
0x1958a0000 - 0x1958cafff libarchive.2.dylib arm64  <6e7ce417e487309c8acc744b1b6b523f> /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib
0x1958cc000 - 0x1958ccfff libassertion_extension.dylib arm64  <0a878153165a30cc84d3c24be2f98c03> /usr/lib/libassertion_extension.dylib
0x19590c000 - 0x19591cfff libbsm.0.dylib arm64  <17b1065f6ad63fe29a30b0a2bd2040b8> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x195920000 - 0x195930fff libbz2.1.0.dylib arm64  <f6ec1b6a4719369aa059ee3269823a2d> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x195934000 - 0x19598afff libc++.1.dylib arm64  <c8e65982941e374c95463384e600181d> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x19598c000 - 0x1959aefff libc++abi.dylib arm64  <fd49f85cb61d31b582895366ea6c2d01> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x1959b4000 - 0x1959c5fff libcmph.dylib arm64  <dca2c6c0bd65352b947d537395e23ab9> /usr/lib/libcmph.dylib
0x1959c8000 - 0x1959d0fff libcupolicy.dylib arm64  <53ad9e07469e314daba651a127e66b1a> /usr/lib/libcupolicy.dylib
0x195a0c000 - 0x195a28fff libextension.dylib arm64  <85d05987c67c34e8a8a573a941464575> /usr/lib/libextension.dylib
0x195a58000 - 0x195a5dfff libheimdal-asn1.dylib arm64  <8a856e4415413a6db2e2a8b78fe378cc> /usr/lib/libheimdal-asn1.dylib
0x195a60000 - 0x195b53fff libiconv.2.dylib arm64  <3ebb30c258f43c0294bcdeebb48b3fc1> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x195b54000 - 0x195d3bfff libicucore.A.dylib arm64  <ae6ef484826c3b8ca9f1d18f4c4811a0> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x195d50000 - 0x195d51fff liblangid.dylib arm64  <80e626200785352a8d5e98a061ca19b8> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x195d54000 - 0x195d60fff liblockdown.dylib arm64  <cb9b352fbc0c3a6fb46744d756c4b702> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x195d64000 - 0x195d7dfff liblzma.5.dylib arm64  <717d1cd1e6f0343b859370862cce58d6> /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
0x196154000 - 0x19616bfff libmis.dylib arm64  <0d7191ca2e7637888d37764b3752a099> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x1961b4000 - 0x1963b0fff libobjc.A.dylib arm64  <e6224d745a023588af8e5bb67498139a> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x196498000 - 0x1964b5fff libresolv.9.dylib arm64  <fd78cddab3e43bd9a7a6440273b15059> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x1964e8000 - 0x1965b9fff libsqlite3.dylib arm64  <286839512b673f7c938aa79ac70bde15> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x196610000 - 0x196642fff libtidy.A.dylib arm64  <2b69233bafd53bdaafa6d9b1767bbad5> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x196644000 - 0x19664dfff libtzupdate.dylib arm64  <a3cef21075493576ae8972e5e9e69a35> /usr/lib/libtzupdate.dylib
0x196654000 - 0x196742fff libxml2.2.dylib arm64  <d459c3155f4e3a21ab7ae8ac70e8ac30> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x196744000 - 0x19676dfff libxslt.1.dylib arm64  <f3770c5f8ac3313bbe4ef1258ebf5733> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x196770000 - 0x196781fff libz.1.dylib arm64  <2a347410b967358289e8256c913714de> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x196784000 - 0x196788fff libcache.dylib arm64  <d322f485769b3fd5a11bc2aff7265fdf> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x19678c000 - 0x196798fff libcommonCrypto.dylib arm64  <746e607941f93464a600e0ea82daadec> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x19679c000 - 0x19679ffff libcompiler_rt.dylib arm64  <e3a8a97c5ffc3e7e9e521ca9323f20a2> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x1967a0000 - 0x1967a7fff libcopyfile.dylib arm64  <8d29fa6f9e0732cd91371c8382347c27> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x1967a8000 - 0x1967fdfff libcorecrypto.dylib arm64  <e1461eeca37f3fcc90f53846fbc4e440> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x196800000 - 0x196826fff libdispatch.dylib arm64  <4aec79ac9eba3b8aac22af396afb7fa8> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x196828000 - 0x19682afff libdyld.dylib arm64  <4ec9528a0cf33bbca52c59a6a41b9690> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x19682c000 - 0x19682cfff liblaunch.dylib arm64  <8224fcd7ddf93c0d81826478dfe9de27> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x196830000 - 0x196835fff libmacho.dylib arm64  <0344db685d1836a58487e50a9813ff42> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x196838000 - 0x196839fff libremovefile.dylib arm64  <210a9549524d32b2a159c1bcbb99cef8> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x19683c000 - 0x196851fff libsystem_asl.dylib arm64  <8c7671a9964433a6a771b915616573c2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
0x196854000 - 0x196855fff libsystem_blocks.dylib arm64  <f38b7145bed330d98d8d79b8362b03de> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x196858000 - 0x1968d8fff libsystem_c.dylib arm64  <0e41ecce05b53c8fbf02989b5a77fb56> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x1968dc000 - 0x1968defff libsystem_configuration.dylib arm64  <3cd2be3dbdf13815a6f6ecb6ccbabef8> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
0x1968e0000 - 0x1968e1fff libsystem_coreservices.dylib arm64  <f7160bbca993323fa4a38a222a09ed2a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
0x1968e4000 - 0x1968f4fff libsystem_coretls.dylib arm64  <1c8d9579d1ba3381ad339917e22d9c35> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coretls.dylib
0x1968f8000 - 0x196900fff libsystem_dnssd.dylib arm64  <98bf59a5c8d33b1ba5d445cce92c8c15> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x196904000 - 0x196925fff libsystem_info.dylib arm64  <0279f0cba06331fe9120011f7fdf37a9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x196928000 - 0x196948fff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64  <c55d48d74aa0301e8b824be5aa45ea46> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x19694c000 - 0x196968fff libsystem_m.dylib arm64  <4cbac7b28cf5304c94b321f1aebdc7f1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x19696c000 - 0x196985fff libsystem_malloc.dylib arm64  <4d939c30e17e3f9186e66d1924018f6e> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
0x196988000 - 0x1969bffff libsystem_network.dylib arm64  <8f5df837edfb3d11a187e5c776d1e704> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x1969c0000 - 0x1969c6fff libsystem_networkextension.dylib arm64  <11c7db16b69234ec90190ad8edd31503> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
0x1969c8000 - 0x1969d2fff libsystem_notify.dylib arm64  <bd0d3f2b517a3d47aa92d519e9e0e3e9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x1969d4000 - 0x1969d8fff libsystem_platform.dylib arm64  <d68bdced15a13339ab86deedce7dac04> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
0x1969dc000 - 0x1969e4fff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64  <f3b39bb3da273b9981d382fe72ed696a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x1969e8000 - 0x1969eafff libsystem_sandbox.dylib arm64  <892ac97604af3a88afe0a8dc98bf16bd> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x1969ec000 - 0x1969effff libsystem_stats.dylib arm64  <f42e97250fa73cd7b99da0cdf2f204a5> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_stats.dylib
0x1969f0000 - 0x1969f6fff libsystem_trace.dylib arm64  <7aa5ccb9bfa53273bc2fcb72a29f787a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
0x1969f8000 - 0x1969fdfff libunwind.dylib arm64  <58604f27ba6e3df99afdf5544de39f83> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x196a00000 - 0x196a23fff libxpc.dylib arm64  <ad580443238d39978d09004c210d0c18> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
```

Answer (score 8):

`com.ceto.ocakonbes failed to scene-create in time` means your application failed to complete its launch in time.

Looking at the stack trace you're calling `+[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:]`, a synchronous network request.

Your application's startup time therefore depends on how fast the network is. From where Apple are, the network request takes too long and the launch times out.

Ideally use an asynchronous fetch instead; at least make sure you return from `applicationDidFinishLaunching` promptly and start the synchronous request later (even if as the immediate next thing on the run loop).

Answer (score 1):

Always look at your code Exception section (`Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d`)

> - The exception code `0x8badf00d` indicates that an application has been terminated by iOS because a watchdog timeout occurred. The application took too long to launch, terminate, or respond to system events. One common cause of this is doing synchronous networking on the main thread. Whatever operation is on Thread 0: needs to be moved to a background thread, or processed differently, so that it does not block the main thread.

[Exception codes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2151/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008184-CH1-ANALYZING_CRASH_REPORTS-EXCEPTION_CODES) (all of them, just FYI)

> - watchdog - .... . If your application fails to respond to certain user interface events (launch, suspend, resume, terminate) in time, the watchdog will kill your application and generate a watchdog timeout crash report.

[Exception Codes: 0x8badf00d](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1693/_index.html) (that is the reason)

Then just in addition to @Tommy in such methods like

`applicationDidFinishLaunching:`
`application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`
`applicationWillResignActive:`
`applicationDidEnterBackground:`
`applicationWillEnterForeground:`
`applicationDidBecomeActive:`
`applicationWillTerminate:`

These are mentioned in an article: [Demystifying iOS Application Crash Logs](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23704/demystifying-ios-application-crash-logs).

You should not block the main thread for any significant amount of time because the watchdog will make its job.

> Remember that the main thread is responsible for running the user interface.

**All other work which could take any significant amount of time just do asynchronously**.

Saw one more way out: [How to avoid 0x8badf00d crash](http://iphonesdksolutions.blogspot.com/2012/08/how-to-avoid-0x8badf00d-crash.html)